# BBCode not working

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I have developed a BBCode for my PHP website to make a tab page for posting. I debugged the BBCode using a separate webpage and found no errors; however, the posting page isn't showing up.

**BBCODE :**

```
[tab1]{TEXT}[/tab1]
```

**HTML replacement :**

```
<div id="tabContainer">
<ul>       

</ul>    

</div>

<script>
var str = {TEXT};
var res = str.split("|");
var n = res.length/2;
var j = 0;
(alert n);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabs = $("#tabContainer").tabs();
    var tabCounter = 1;


  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){ 

        var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
        var current_idx = ul.find("li").length + 1;

        $("<li><a href='#fragment-" + current_idx + "'>" + res[j] + "</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );

        tabs.append("<div id='fragment-" + current_idx + "'>" + res[j+1] + "</div>");
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabs.tabs("select", 1);
        j=j+2;

  };

}); 
</script>
```

In overallheader.html, I added the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Example :**

```
<tab1>"1|Page1|2|Page2|3|Page3|4|Page4|5|Page5"</tab1>
```

[The Result of BBCODE](http://imgur.com/Ruh1Hzi)

http://jsfiddle.net/rashlak/5GzR8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have [solved the issue myself](http://jsfiddle.net/5GzR8/5/) :)

Thanks guys.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    str = $("li[id='xx']", "#tabContainer").text();
    $("li[id='xx']", "#tabContainer").remove();


    alert(str);
//var str = "1|Page1|2|Page2|3|Page3|4|Page4|5|Page5";
var res = str.split("|");
var n = res.length/2;
var j = 0;
var tabs = $("#tabContainer").tabs();
var tabCounter = 1;

alert(n);
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){ 

        var ul = tabs.find( "ul" );
        var current_idx = ul.find("li").length + 1;

        $("<li><a href='#fragment-" + current_idx + "'>" + res[j] + "</a></li>" ).appendTo( ul );

        tabs.append("<div id='fragment-" + current_idx + "'>" + res[j+1] + "</div>");
        tabs.tabs("refresh");
        tabs.tabs("select", 1);
        j=j+2;

  };    
})

<div id="tabContainer">
    <ul>        
         <li id="xx">1|Page1|2|Page2|3|Page3|4|Page4|5|Page7</li>    
    </ul>       
</div>
```